# How to put Javascript file (.js file) in a web server?

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, webserver

I want to put javascript in a web server. After that I need to inject that script in c# code using src="http:\...". Please tell me what to do from the beginning

Comment: what are you trying to do? Be more specific .

Comment: Try to grab hardly your js file and throw it direct to the web server hole. you need to hit this hole before you call again by playing Ocarina with "Bolero of fire song" - PRINTED –

Answer (score 0):

Try this to inject the `javascript` file content from the `C#`.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(), 
    "scriptname", 
    "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/scripts/test.js' />",
    false);
```